# web3.py query for Uniswap V3 Factory contract events on Arbitrum, getting all pools created since block 0, but it's missing multiple token pairs

Tags: python-3.x, ethereum, blockchain, web3py, infura

I'm using web3.py to parse through all liquidity pools created since block 0 on Uniswap V3 Arbitrum. Atm, about 486 different pools a returned, but none of them are pool I'm expecting. Is there some other reason why the pools might not be showing up? These two tokens are not found: `Ramses (0xaaa6c1e32c55a7bfa8066a6fae9b42650f262418)` and `PLX (0xc8ccbd97b96834b976c995a67bf46e5754e2c48e)`. They both have token pools on v3 Uniswao Arbitrum.

```
infura_url = "https://{arbitrum-mainnet.infura.io/INFURA_ID"
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(RPC_URL))

# Uniswap V3 Factory contract
contract = web3.eth.contract("0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984", ABI)

pools = contract.events["PoolCreated"]().getLogs(fromBlock=from_block, toBlock=to_block).get_all_entries()

for each in pools:
    # Search pools for PLX token
    if each["token0"].lower() == "0xc8ccbd97b96834b976c995a67bf46e5754e2c48e" or each["token1"].lower() == "0xc8ccbd97b96834b976c995a67bf46e5754e2c48e"\
                == "":
        # Expecting PLX/WETH pool (0x7e48e98c9841bdd965986d2a4b37457938b27ee3)
        # But returns nothing instead
        print(each["pool")
        break
```

Comment: Does the event show up in the RPC provider if you query it some other way? Have you tried alternative RPC providers and confirmed it's not a problem with Infura?